# regular expression incorrect validation

Tags: java, regex

can anyone please explain me why this regex doesn't catch the input. I need to catch the special characters mentioned in the regex.

```
        final String REGEX="[.,%*$#@?^<!&>'|/\\\\~\\[\\]{}+=\"-]*";


        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("2c450807-4a4c-4f18-bf4f-5a100ced87a0");

        if (matcher.matches()) {

            System.out.println("found");

        }
        else{

            System.out.println("not found!");
        }
```

This prints the "not found!". Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `matcher.matches()` use:

```
matcher.find()
```

`matcher.matches()` expects to match complete input otherwise.

Also better to use this regex:

```
final String REGEX="[.,%*$#@?^<!&>'|/\\\\~\\[\\]{}+=\"-]";
```

Putting `*` in front will make it match empty string also.

Comment: You should have done what I have. Closed as duplicate.

Comment: Actually there were more than one issue I was addressing in my answer and dup answer was addressing first part.

Comment: Ok, if you feel it that way, feel free to un-dupe the question.